# Bing Maps incompatibility with MooTools

Tags: mootools, bing-maps

I have an existing project that uses MooTools that I would like to add a Bing Map to.  I've discovered, however, that MooTools breaks Bing Maps.  I'm kind of at a loss of how to fix this.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qgvb5q2h/) is a jsfiddle that shows the problem.  If you watch your console when you click the Run button, you'll see that Bing throws an exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.open is not a function
```

If you then disable MooTools, and hit run again, you'll see the map appears in the results pane.

How do I get past this?  Is this a bug?--in Bing or in MooTools?

The existing project that I have uses MooTools 1.3.2, but the issue shows up even in 1.6.0.

Comment: Strange. MooTools appears to be overwriting something in the code that Bing Maps downloads. Will have the Bing Maps dev team take a look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) breaks Bing Maps API loading since it extends [`Element` object with `send` method](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/70afaa8321d53fa21511d1fedf3979a7e32b8626/Source/Request/Request.js):

```
Element.implement({

    send: function(url){
        var sender = this.get('send');
        sender.send({data: this, url: url || sender.options.url});
        return this;
    }

});
```

Bing Maps library internally has the dependency to the same method used for loading suplementary library files.  `

A *workaround* would be to remove `MooTools` specific method:

```
delete Element.prototype.send;
```

Demo: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zBglw4zOinmEwyH58kwe)

Comment: One could also say Bing breaks the MooTools API :) `+1`