# Bing Map api V8 map control: Uncaught TypeError: n.open is not a function

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

On calling

$.getScript('https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap', false)

I am getting following:

[image]

Comment: Which framework are you using jQuery? Which version? Which browsers does this occur in?

Answer (score 0):

I see you also posted on the [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/954c8ad0-0f53-4801-b0d8-e25f2f095713/bing-map-api-v8-map-control-uncaught-typeerror-nopen-is-not-a-function?forum=bingmapsajax) with slightly different details and also contacted the Bing Maps support team. You are using the frozen branch of Bing Maps V8 with MooTools and seeing this issue. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185594/bing-maps-incompatibility-with-mootools), MooTools is overwriting something which is breaking Bing Maps. The Bing Maps team is looking into options to handle this from their side.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I was trying out ways to resolve the issue. After referring the doc, I added branch experimental, frozen, release randomly. Even without using branch prefix the issue persists. Let me know.

Comment: As noted, the issue is with MooTools overwriting a standard browser feature. The Bing Maps team is investigating if there is any workarounds that they can implement when this happens. If a workaround if made it will show up in the experimental branch first, then the main release branch, and eventually the frozen branch.

Comment: But I am not using mootools or similar Thats what make me confused regarding exact issue. The MooTools compatibility has alreday been railsed on this forum Have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061241/bing-maps-api-v8

Comment: The only report we have had with this issue so far has been with MooTools and that just recently came, so looked like this was the same query.